# Smallest graph possessing a property

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I was studying about *Almost self-centered graphs*.

http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10114-011-9628-3

My doubt is what would be the minimum number of vertices for such graphs.

My idea: I think its 4 and the graph that satisfy this condition is $P_4$ where end vertices are not in the center of $P_4$. Is my solution correct? If not, then kindly give hints or suggestions, thanks.

***Definition :*** Almost self-centered (ASC) graphs are introduced as the graphs with exactly two non-central vertices.

***NOTE :***  there is another class of graphs known as almost peripheral graphs. Almost peripheral (AP) graphs are introduced as graphs G with |P(G)| = |V (G)|−1 (and |C(G)| = 1). I think $P_3$ is AP graph

Comment: Why is $P_3$ not an ASC graph?

Comment: @PeterKošinár  because there is another class of graphs known as almost peripheral graphs. Almost peripheral
(AP) graphs are introduced as graphs G with |P(G)| = |V (G)|−1 (and |C(G)| = 1). I think $P_3$ is AP graph

Comment: What is $P(G)$ and what is $C(G)$?

Comment: @bof P(G) is the set of vertices having maximum eccentricity and C(G) is the center of graph containing vertices of minimum ecc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u \sim v \sim w$ be the path on three vertices. The vertex $v$ is the unique center, since it has [eccentricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_%28graph_theory%29) equal to 1, while the eccentricities of both $u$ and $w$ are equal to 2. Thus, the path on three vertices has precisely two non-central vertices ($u$ and $v$), which conforms to your definition of almost self-centered graphs.

Comment: I am sorry to say that I gave some info in above comment.  there is another class of graphs known as almost peripheral graphs. Almost peripheral (AP) graphs are introduced as graphs G with |P(G)| = |V (G)|−1 (and |C(G)| = 1). I think $P_3$ is AP graph.

Comment: Is there any reason $P_3$ cannot belong to both classes?

Comment: that's where I am confused. In a way $P_3$ satisfying conditions of both definitions.

Comment: @monalisa There is no problem with a graph satisfying many definitions at once. The graph $P_3$ also satisfies the definition of "path" and "order 3" and "$(1,2)$-regular". Interesting graphs have many properties.

Comment: sir is it possible to construct an AP graph on 4 vertices where radius = 2. I feel that the its possible to get an AP graph on 4 vertices where radius  =1 only.

Comment: @monalisa Sorry to ping you, but I added some thoughts to [our chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11990/discussion-between-austin-mohr-and-monalisa).